# How to separate React router and nodejs api

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm kind of new in react and trying to develop sample app based on reactjs + expressjs + nodejs referred by https://github.com/lmammino/judo-heroes but problem is when I'm trying to create webhook api for 3rd party application, react router showed me as 404 page.

**server.js**

```
import routes from './routes';
...
...
var webhook = require('./routes/webhook');
app.use('webhook', webhook);
```

and **routes.js**

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import IndexPage from './components/IndexPage';
import NotFoundPage from './components/NotFoundPage';

const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <IndexRoute component={IndexPage}/>
    <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>
  </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

and when I called "**localhost:3333/webhook**", it gone to execute `<Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage}/>` as showed 404 error page.

Please help me how can I export webhook as individual api not related to react router?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are trying to render client side routes in the same way you are for server side and this is causing a conflict between the routing in React + Express. I'd suggest you are probably using `browserHistory` and I would swap to `hashHistory` as this means the client side is rendered differently compared to express routes. By swapping to hash your routes in react become rendered via `/#/index`. This allows express to render API routes in the traditional format like `/api/webhook`. You can read more about histories here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#histories

Hope this helps

Dylan

Answer (score 0):

You should mount your `webhook` router with a leading slash:

```
app.use('/webhook', webhook);
```

This should be executed before `app.get('*', ...` wildcard handler to prevent React app from being served and bootstrapped.